# Unable to pass the arguments to R function from cpp code

Tags: c++, r

My cpp source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
cout<<"Before"<<endl;
system("Rscript /Desktop/R_TENS/rtest.R");
return 0;
}
```

rtest.R

```
rtest = function(input ,output){
     a <- input

   b<- output

   outpath<-a*b
   print(a*b)
   return(outpath)
 }

Compile: g++ name.cpp
```

This creates a executable file. But how the parameters (eg:2,3) is could be passed? 
`./a.out 2 3` is not working. Expected result for this input is 6.

Comment: Guessing, maybe because we are not passing args in `system` call in cpp code, also we are just defining a function in rtest.R and not calling it?

Comment: In `rtest.R` you just defined the function without actually calling it. See `?commandArgs` to pass arguments from the command line to a R script.

Comment: Your R script only defines a function. Change it to call the function using command line arguments as input. Once the script works on the command line, you have to add the command line arguments of the C++ program to the system call.